# $.trim() jQuery not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I am having issues with using $.trim() in IE it works just fine in firefox. Does anyone see any reason this would fail. Thank you.

```
$('#GuestEmailAddress').on('blur', function () {                
            var $inputValue = $(this).val();
            $.trim($inputValue);
            $(this).val($inputValue); 
        });
```

Comment: Which version(s) of IE?

Comment: trim does not manipulate the variable you pass into it, it _returns_ the trimmed value …

Comment: Strings are immutable in JS. There is no function that modifies an existing string. Functions like `trim` return a different string, so you must rewrite it: `$inputValue = $.trim($inputValue)`

Comment: @Oriol That's an answer, not a comment!

Comment: How could this faulty code work in Firefox?

Comment: This is what I eneded up using to fix this  
    $(this).val($.trim($(this).val()));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the line ...

```
$.trim($inputValue);
```

... to ...

```
$inputValue = $.trim($inputValue);
```

The first does not change the `$inputValue`, it simply returns the new string which in the second set of code I am assigning to a value that can then be used later in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code as follows...

delete:

```
$.trim($inputValue);
```

change:

```
var $inputValue = $(this).val();
```

to:

```
var $inputValue = $(this).val().trim();
```

Comment: The last line is using the built-in [`String.prototype.trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) function, which is not supported in older browsers (particularly IE8 and below).  Since jQuery is explicitly used in the question, it's probably best to use jQuery's [`$.trim`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.trim/) function instead, especially since the question uses that function already.

Comment: I would but that would fail in IE 8